# Java multi threaded Atomic Integer increment on error

Tags: java, atomic

So I have a little problem. I am checking lots of numbers in a loop, where the number is just an `AtomicInteger` that is incremented every time. The problem is that sometimes there is an "error" (the error has to do with the server, not program) and the thread needs to sleep. After they sleep, I would like all of the threads to go back and recheck the numbers that they missed because of the error, but it will only recheck the last one, because the `AtomicInteger` was already incremented. Here is my code:

```
public class Red extends java.lang.Thread {
        private final LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer> queue;

    public Red(LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

        public void run()
    {
while(true){
    try{
int i = queue.take();
Main.code.setValueAttribute(""+i);
HtmlPage reply = (HtmlPage)Main.btnFinal.click();
Main.webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(Main.r.nextInt(500));
if ( reply.asText().indexOf( "Error" ) > -1 || reply.asText().indexOf( "unavailable" ) > -1) {
int sleep = Main.r.nextInt(900000);
System.out.println(" error, on "+i+" sleeping for "+ sleep);
Thread.sleep(sleep);
continue;
}
System.out.println("Code "+i+" checked.");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        continue;
    }
}

        }
}
```

Here is my code for to star the threads:

```
List<LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>> queuelist = new ArrayList<LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>>();
   for (int n = 0; n < threads; n++) {
    queuelist.add(new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>());
    java.lang.Thread t = new Red(queuelist.get(n));
    t.start();
   }
java.lang.Thread a = new MainThread(queuelist);
a.start();
```

Here is my code for MainThread:

```
public class MainThread extends java.lang.Thread {
    final private List<LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>> queues;
    final private AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(10000000);

    public MainThread(List<LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>> queues) {
        this.queues = queues;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            int temp = atomicInteger.getAndIncrement();
            for(LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer> queue : queues) {
                queue.offer(temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem, then one solution is to give each thread its own `BlockingQueue<Integer>` or `ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Integer>`; the main thread's loop will then increment the `AtomicInteger` and `offer` its value to each of the queues, and the threads will `take` or `poll` on their queues to retrieve the integers and process them.  This way if a thread sleeps it won't miss any integers - they'll be waiting for it in its queue when it wakes up.

```
public class MainThread extends java.lang.Thread {
    final private List<BlockingQueue<Integer>> queues;
    final private AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger();

    public MainThread(List<BlockingQueue<Integer>> queues) {
        this.queues = queues;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            int temp = atomicInteger.getAndIncrement();
            for(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue : queues) {
                queue.offer(temp);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class WorkerThread extends java.lang.Thread {
    private final BlockingQueue<Integer> queue;

    public WorkerThread(BlockingQueue<Integer> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            int temp = queue.take();
            // process temp
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think I understand. Could you give me a link to some sort of tutorial? Or give me some sort of example? Thanks.

Comment: @user1947236 [Here is a blocking queue tutorial that might help](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/09/java-concurrency-tutorial-blocking.html)

Comment: I still am not really understanding how to implement it, could you maybe provide me with an example of how I would implement it into my code? That would be great!

Comment: @user1947236 see my edited answer.  Create one main thread and as many worker threads as you want; each worker thread gets its own queue, and the main thread gets a list of all of the queues.  If a worker thread sleeps then it won't miss any integers because they'll be waiting in the queue.

Comment: So do I need to start worker threads from the thread named "MainThread" or can I start worker threads from the actual main thread of my program? I am trying to start the "MainThread" and "WorkerThreads" from the actual main thread of my program, but don't know what to give WorkerThread as a parameter when starting it.

Comment: @user1947236 You can start the `WorkerThreads` from the main thread.  Initialize an `ArrayList<BlockingQueue>` and give each `WorkerThread` a separate `BlockingQueue` (from the `ArrayList`) in its constructor, then give the `MainThread` the `ArrayList<BlockingQueue>` in its constructor.

Comment: I am trying to do it like this, but it seems to not be working: ArrayList<BlockingQueue> queuelist = new ArrayList<BlockingQueue>();
java.lang.Thread t = new MainThread(queuelist);
It says that MainTread takes a List, not ArrayList.

Comment: @user1947236 Use `List<BlockingQueue> queuelist = new ArrayList<BlockingQueue>();`

Comment: `List<BlockingQueue<Integer>> queuelist = new ArrayList<BlockingQueue<Integer>>();
java.lang.Thread a = new MainThread(queuelist);
a.start();
   for (int n = 1; n <= threads; n++) {
    java.lang.Thread t = new Red(queuelist.get(0));
    t.start();
   }`
Should that work? I am getting index out of bounds... Probably because I didn't add anything to the list?

Comment: @user1947236 you'll need to add one queue per worker thread to the list - you'll probably want to use `LinkedBlockingQueue`s. You will also need to initialize the worker threads with the same queues that are in the list so the threads can talk to each other

Comment: I went trough and changed all the BlockingQueues into LinkedBlockingQueues in the main thread, WorkerThread, and MainThread, and changed it so its like this, but it still gets out of bounds: `List<LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>> queuelist = new ArrayList<LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>>();
java.lang.Thread a = new MainThread(queuelist);
a.start();
   for (int n = 0; n < threads; n++) {
       queuelist.set(n, new LinkedBlockingQueue());
    java.lang.Thread t = new Red(queuelist.get(n));
    t.start();
   }`

Comment: @user1947236 the problem is `queuelist.get(n)` - the indexes only go up to n-1

Comment: I dont know if you saw that I changed n=1 to n=0? Because when I try to get n-1, I get out of bounds.

Comment: `for (int n = 0; n < threads; n++) {
       queuelist.add(new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>());
    java.lang.Thread t = new Red(queuelist.get(n));
    t.start();
   }`
That seems to work, except I keep getting java.util.ConcurrentModificationException randomly...

Comment: @user1947236 That exception means that one thread is iterating over the list while another thread is adding to it, which includes iterating over the list with a for-each loop.  Be certain that the list is initialized with all of its queues before any code tries to use it. I suspect the problem is that you're starting `MainThread` before the list is initialized - wait to start `MainThread` until after the for loop that initializes the list.

Comment: @user1947236 For cases like this where a data structure shouldn't be modified after initialization, it's often a good idea to use something like an [UnmodifiableList](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/list/UnmodifiableList.html) that enforces this - it can help eliminate the weird run-time behavior that can result when a supposedly read-only collection get modified. In your case it would prevent the `ConcurrentModificationException` by ensuring that the list is initialized before anybody iterates over it

Comment: So I should just change list to UnmodifiableList?

Comment: @user1947236 First try delaying the start of `MainThread`. If that doesn't work, *then* change to an unmodifiable list.

Comment: What do you mean "delaying" it? Don't I need to start it before the worker threads?

Comment: @user1947236 It's safest if you start it after the worker threads - this ensures that the worker threads don't miss any data

Comment: When I start the MainThread after the worker threads, all of the threads seem to be checking the same 3 or 4 numbers for about 30 iterations, and then after that, they simply stop checking anything.

Comment: @user1947236 I don't see anything wrong with `MainThread` or with the initialization code. Post the worker thread code as well.

Comment: The workerThread is named Red, it is the first snippet of code.

Comment: @user1947236 I don't see what would be causing that behavior. Put a `println(temp)` in the main thread after the `getAndIncrement` call and a `println(i)` in the worker thread after the `take` call to see if that helps diagnose the problem.

Comment: This is after running for around 5-10 seconds: http://pastebin.com/N6Thxwbs, after that, it is just Print after getAndIncrement in main thread for another 50k numbers... Edit: Actually, there are a few Code 1000000x checked in there... Like 3 or 4.

Comment: @user1947236 Reduce the sleep time on your worker threads - right now you're having them sleep for up to 15 minutes. Half a second i.e. `Thread.sleep(500)` would be more reasonable.

Comment: Well that is only if the server gives an error, if the server gives an error, the threads need to wait for a few minutes. There were no errors from server during this test.

Comment: @user1947236 In that case try calling `Thread.yield()` in the main thread after every twenty iterations

Comment: It seems to be doing the same things... How would I try using an unmodifiable list?

Comment: @user1947236 Add the apache commons jar to your class path, and change the `List` in your main thread to an `UnmodifiableList`.  This probably isn't the problem though - one of the methods being called by your worker thread is probably hanging (blocking on an event that isn't occurring, going into an infinite loop, etc).

Comment: When trying to change to an unmodifiable list, it says org.apache.commons.collections.list.UnmodifiableList does not take parameters.